# Easeljs keep object within bounds

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs

I am working on a drawing application in HTML5 canvas, using Easeljs. So far I am able to drag and drop objects into the field, but I only want them within certain bounds.

**To illustrate:**
[image: Drawing app]

Objects 1, 2, 4 and 5 should get deleted, but object 3 should be kept.

I have tried using hitTest(), but that didn't work properly (I probably did something wrong). I would love to post the code I used, but my PC froze while working on it... Thought I'd better ask while unfreezing, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
var obj1 = obj.getBounds().clone(); // obj = a pylon
var e = obj1.getTransformedBounds();
var obj2 = bg.getBounds().clone(); // bg = the big green field
var f = obj2.getTransformedBounds();

if(e.x < f.x || e.x + e.width > f.x + f.width) return false;
if(e.y < f.y || e.y + e.height > f.y + f.height) return false;

return true;
```

After all it's so simple, but I guess I was working on it for so long that I started to think too hard...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick drag and drop sample with bounds constraining:

http://jsfiddle.net/xrqatyLs/8/

The secret sauce is just in constraining the drag position to your own values.

```
clip.x = Math.max(bounds.x, Math.min(bounds.x + bounds.width - clipWidth, evt.stageX)); 
clip.y = Math.max(bounds.y, Math.min(bounds.y + bounds.height-clipHeight, evt.stageY));
```

Here is another more complex example that manually checks if one rectangle intersects another rectangle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/yvfLwdzn/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your second fiddle helped a bit! Unfortunately, it doesn't work proper enough. See the following link for the result: http://i.imgur.com/7mwPErY.png 1 and 4 get deleted, but not 2 and 3. The red box around the field shows its bounding box (= the area where the pylons shouldn't get deleted).